# Editing "bug"? [Edit removed during grace period]

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits

> [Edit removed during grace period]

is what is autofilled in the comment box when I'm trying to make an edit within 5 minutes of my last edit (this is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23989142/218196).

[image]

While it seems I just have to change the editing reason, it probably shouldn't be pre-filled with an internal reason.

---

**Note:** Maybe this was a one time thing or weird race condition (I did make some quick successive edits). I would be interested to know if anybody can repro this.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it with a trivial attempt - but the diff for that edit is nothing so the existing edit summary is at least accurate. What do you suggest, since the edit summary is just a comment, and that's what is stored for that particular revision? As to how: Is it possible you were editing the same post in multiple browser windows or something similar?

Comment: I did indeed add more information, and removed it immediately because the OP updated their question. I did not edit the post in multiple windows. So this might be "by design" but I think it would still be better to not pre-populate the comment box with the internal reason. It was certainly surprising for me. We could just leave the comment box blank in this case.

Answer (score 7):

This comment gets auto generated when your current edit within the grace period would be the equivalent of reverting/rolling back to the last revision created before the grace period started (edits withing the grace period always update the same revision).

The repro case was to do a change to an older-than-the-grace-period post, and then do another edit that undid the previous change. After that the inline-editor would always show the mentioned comment. The posts/{id}/edit route already handled the case, whereas the inline editor didn't. The fix is rolling out with the next build (build rev `2015.9.25.3713` on MSE/MSO, `2015.9.25.2842` on sites).