# "Edit removed during grace period" while gracing, I'm sorry, what?

Tags: feature-request, bug, edits

I [made a few quick edits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32761760/111575), all of them were additive, but at the third of them received a: `[Edit removed during grace period]` error, subsequently prohibiting me from further edits.

While I [understand the grace period](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262810/edit-removed-during-grace-period) (I use it a lot) and noticed [a related, but not the same bug report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257981/editing-bug-edit-removed-during-grace-period), I would like you to consider two issues here:

1. The message appeared with additive edits, the post did not return to its original state, though I did do a refresh of the page (but no re-post).
2. It prevents the user from further editing, unless he removes this message.

The second is, I think, the more serious of the two. With me, all alarm bells went off, thinking I was considered some rogue editor, spammer or something else being blocked from the system. The text, being a system text, suggests "Hey, you made an edit, but we didn't like it, we removed it for you and now you cannot edit any further".

I am sure that is not intended. I suggest a fix along this line:

- Allow subsequent edits by the same user
- Change the text slightly, or only fill the reason-field *after* the grace period is gone so that it doesn't bother the user while still gracing

[image]

Comment: Possibly editing a post after it has had a revision removed within the grace period? Sometimes it grabs the reason for the previous edit to put in the reason box.

Comment: To clarify the previous comment: it doesn't look like you received an error reading "[Edit removed during grace period]". It looks like you received an error reading "Comment reserved for system use", where the comment in question was the text "[Edit removed during grace period]". The system appears to have filled this text in for your edit, presumably due to some glitch, but that exact text is reserved by the system for its own use. Just delete the text and/or replace it with your own custom edit reason and everything should be fine, I think.

Comment: Looking into this. This comment gets auto generated when your current edit within the grace period would be the equivalent of reverting/rolling back to the last revision created before the grace period started (edits withing the grace period always update the same revision).... Not sure how that comment can leak back into the comment input though.

Comment: @m0sa, looks like what happened is indeed that that text got pre-filled in the edit-reason field, blocking submitting the edit (while still in the grace period). Workaround suggested by Peter probably works, but after I wrote this report, the grace period was over so I couldn't test. Regardless, I don't think that it should "leak" into the edit-reason box, preventing further edits...

Comment: Yes, I marked this question as a duplicate, see original for full answer